# Filter for noobs

Tags: 2013, filter, connection-filters

I'm trying to learn about filters in SharePoint. A colleague tried to setup alerts for his tasks. He made a view filtering all of his tasks out of his departments tasks and then created an alarm about change of ownership. When he got flooded with mails from all his colleagues tasks he asked us to implement what he meant to do.

I tried to but I don't get it. To achieve this I'm trying to filter my testsystems tasks with a textfilter, and it doesn't work. My tasks contain titles with the words "child", "filter" or "oil". So what did I do:

1. Create Textfilter Webpart.
2. Define default value "child"
3. Click Apply
4. Create Connection between Textfilter and taskslist by

...clicking on the little icon next to the checkbox to open the context menu of the Textfilter, chose connections and chose "Send filter values to". A dialog box appeared asking for type of connection type with the options "Get Parameters from" and "Get Filter Values from". First gets me an error on the next page, 2nd takes me to connection configuration. Now I get to choose from all columns in my tasklist. I guess this is the column the textfilter is looking up to match. So far I tried assigned to and entered Names of persons that have tasks assigned to them, but the list always showed all entried. Same with tasks title columns, no isolated child, no oil, the list will always show all tasks.

So obviously I got something horribly wrong in my intuitive understanding of SharePoint webpart filtering. Please enlighten me as all material I could find on this topic is not noobish enough. I don't know the difference between get filter values and the other stuff I could choose from, but I'm in a learning by doing position with little to no budget for trainings and stuff.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: May some Administrator care to delete this post? If it contributes, which I doubt, I could elaborate about not setting Render Server in my tasks list webpart but I would consider the noob level too high...